# Browser caheing of url redirects

Tags: http, redirect, rfc2616

Does browsers caches target locations of request redirects? eg.

```
http://example.org/assets?ts=3248723642873 [302]
 -> http://example.org/css/test.css
     -> download
http://example.org/assets?ts=766773 [302]
 -> http://example.org/css/test.css
     -> from cache
http://example.org/assets?ts=saa766773 [302]
 -> http://example.org/css/test.css
     -> from cache
```

From my test i conclude that there are not but want to be sure.

Comment: 1) That may be browser specific and 2) it depends on if the HTTP status was 301 or 302.

Comment: browsers cache redirects (pin http://example.org/assets?ts=3248723642873 with http://example.org/css/test.css), but there are seam to ignore target location of redirect even it's pointing to the same url regardless of status code